# How to insert numbers into a binary search tree in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert a list of numbers into a binary search tree by calling the TREEinsert function frim the main function however whenever my program runs it does not print any number inserted into the binary search tree. I have gone over both my TREEinsert function and Displayinorder function but cannot seem to find any issues with the functionality of either function. I have a basic understanding of binary search trees and have looked at many examples trying to get an insight as to how BST's work. Any guidance will be greatly helpful.

```
struct node
 {
     int info;
     struct node *left;
     struct node *right;
 };



void TREEclear(struct node* t)
{
     t = NULL;
}

void TREEinsert(struct node*  t, int x)
{

    //insert in BST
    if(t == NULL)
    {
        t = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->info = x;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (x < t->info)
        TREEinsert(t->left, x);
        if (x > t->info)
            TREEinsert(t->right, x);
    }
}

void Displayinorder(struct node* t)
{
    //in order: (LC)(P)(RC)
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        Displayinorder(t->left); //LC
        printf("%d\t", t->info); //P
        Displayinorder(t->right); //RC
    }
}

struct node *root;

int main()
{
    TREEclear(root);

    TREEinsert(root, 5);
    TREEinsert(root, 8);
    TREEinsert(root, 2);
    TREEinsert(root, 6);

    Displayinorder(root);

    printf("\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `t` is a local variable in `TREEinsert`. Any changes you make to it are not refceted in the calling function. You should pass the address of the root pointer as `struct node **p`.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node pointer `t` is a local variable in `TREEinsert`. Any changes you make to it are not reflected in the calling function.

You should pass the address of the root pointer as `struct node *p` from the calling function. When you recurse, pass the adress of the left or right pointer of te current node respectively.

Here's how:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};


void TREEclear(struct node *t)
{
    t = NULL;
}

void TREEinsert(struct node **t, int x)
{
    if (*t == NULL) {
        *t = malloc(sizeof(**t));
        // TODO: check allocation success

        (*t)->info = x;
        (*t)->left = NULL;
        (*t)->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if (x < (*t)->info) TREEinsert(&(*t)->left, x);
        if (x > (*t)->info) TREEinsert(&(*t)->right, x);
    }
}

void Displayinorder(struct node *t)
{
    if (t != NULL) {
        Displayinorder(t->left);
        printf("%d\n", t->info);
        Displayinorder(t->right);
    }

}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = NULL;

    TREEinsert(&root, 5);
    TREEinsert(&root, 8);
    TREEinsert(&root, 2);
    TREEinsert(&root, 6);

    Displayinorder(root);

    // TODO: need to free the tree nodes

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you pass `&root` to the insertion function, which may have to modify it, but just `root` to the display functon, which only has to inspect it.

I've gotten rid of your `TREEclear` function. First, it has the same problems as your original `TREEinsert`: it modifies a local variable and doesn't change anything in `main`. Second, this function should `free` all nodes, not just set the root to `NULL`. (That said, you should write this function, so that you can deallocate the tree after use.)

Answer (score 2):

The `t` in your `TREEinsert` function is a local variable so from there you have two options: either you return it and have the code like below, or your parameter `t` should be a `struct node**`
So first option is:

```
 struct node* TREEinsert(struct node*  t, int x)
 {

  //insert in BST
  if(t == NULL)
  {

    t = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    t->info = x;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
    return t ;
  }
 else
  {
    if (x < t->info)
        return(TREEinsert(t->left, x));
    if (x > t->info)
       return(TREEinsert(t->right, x));
  }


}
```

Second option is:

```
void TREEinsert(struct node **t, int x)
{
    if (*t == NULL) {
        *t = malloc(sizeof(**t));
        (*t)->info = x;
        (*t)->left = NULL;
        (*t)->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if (x < (*t)->info) 
            TREEinsert(&(*t)->left, x);
        if (x > (*t)->info) 
            TREEinsert(&(*t)->right, x);
    }
}
```

Side-note: you may want to check whether your `malloc` succeeded or not.

Answer (score 2):

First of all function `TREEclear` does not set to zero the original head of three. It deals with a copy of the head. The original head is not changed.

Also the name of the function is confusing. It is better to name it for example like  `TREEinit`.

It can look the following way

```
void TREEinit( struct node * *t)
{
    *t = NULL;
}
```

Recursive function `TREEinsert`  can look like

```
void TREEinsert( struct node * *t, int x )
{
    if ( *t == NULL )
    {
        *t = ( struct node* )malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        ( *t )->info = x;
        ( *t )->left = NULL;
        ( *t )->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (  x < ( *t )->info )
    {       
        TREEinsert( &( *t )->left, x );
    }
    else if ( x > ( *t )->info )
    {
        TREEinsert( &( *t )->right, x );
    }
}
```

and it should be called like

```
TREEinsert( &root, 5 );
```

Take into account that you need to write also a function that will free all allocated memory for the tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
There is two way to fixed it
1. change the return type of Insert function 


Struct node * TREEinsert(){
              //your code

            return the local variable( t)
           }

2. If you don't want to change the return type of function then change the argument you are passing to Insert function
            TREEinsert(&root, intVariable);
    and in  TREEinsert(Struct node **,int);
```